# N-dimensional array into single array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, n-dimensional, arrayofarrays

I have an array of lists and I want to convert it into single dimensional array. I can do it with 2 "for" loops but one prohibition is that I have to do it as it was N-dimensional array.

```
original_list = [[2,4,3,[1,2]],[1,5,6], [9], [7,9,0]]
```

Comment: This is actually a different question @prune. Try applying any of those methods and you will get alist of lists and inegers

Comment: The actial duplicate is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: @nixon I the dup I used, at least two of the answers deal with arbitrary nesting levels.  However, the one you gave is easier to find; I've added it to the duplicates list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `chain` from `itertools`:

Code:

```
import itertools as it

original_list = [[2,4,3,[1,2]],[1,5,6], [9], [7,9,0]]

print(original_list)

new_list = list(it.chain.from_iterable(original_list))

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 3, [1, 2]], [1, 5, 6], [9], [7, 9, 0]]
[2, 4, 3, [1, 2], 1, 5, 6, 9, 7, 9, 0]
```

Comment: Oops, almost...

Comment: almost... :D  Thanks for your effort